# Matlab: add unit above the colorbar

Tags: matlab, colorbar

[image]

I have a question about how to add a unit above the colorbar. My code as below:

```
hc=colorbar;
xlabel(hc,'psi');
```

However, it reveals that unit is not above the colorbar.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Replace `xlabel(hc,'psi')` by `title(hc,'psi')`. So the code becomes

```
hc=colorbar;
title(hc,'psi');
```

This gives

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You can use the code as below

```
title(colorbar,'psi','FontSize',24);
```

Comment: You can remove the first `colorbar` statement. The second one creates a new colorbar object that replaces the first (and returns a handle to the new one)

Answer (score 0):

This will display the label to the right of the colorbar:

```
h=colorbar();
ylabel(h,'units');
```